# Applying drools rules using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, drools

We have  scenario  where I have to get data from one database and update data to another database after applying business rules.

I want to use spring **batch+drools+hibernate**.

Can we apply rules in batch as we have million records at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert of drools and I am simply trying to give some context about Spring Batch.

Spring Batch is a **Read -> Process -> Write** framework and what we do with drools is same as what we do in **Process** step of Spring Batch i.e. we transform a read item in an `ItemProcessor`.

How Spring Batch helps you for handling large number of items is by implementing **Chunk Oriented** processing i.e. We read N-number of items in one go, transform these items one by one in Processor & then write a bulk of items in writer - this way we are basically reducing number of DB calls.

There are further scope of performance improvement by implementing parallelism via partitioning etc if your data can be partitioned on some criteria.

So we read items in bulk , transform one by one & then write in bulk to target database & I don't think hibernate is a good tool for bulk update / insert at write step - I would go by plain JDBC.

Your drools comes into picture at transformation step & that is going to be your custom code & its performance will have nothing to do with Spring Batch i.e. how you initialize sessions , pre compile rules etc . You will have to plug in this code in such a way that you don't initialize drools session etc every time but that should be one time activity.